# Maximal $l^2$ restriction of psd quadratic form on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

I've been stuck on this problem for a few days as part of a bigger research problem and am looking for some help.

Let $S : \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a positive definite quadratic form with distinct eigenvalues on $\mathbb{R}^n$. For any vector space $V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, this form can be restricted to a form on $V$ via $S\rvert_{V \times V}$.

Fix a subspace $W \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and an integer $k$ with $\dim(W) \leq k \leq n$. I want to compute
$$V = \operatorname{argmax}_{\substack{W \subset V' \subset \mathbb{R}^n \\ \dim(V') = k}} \lVert S\rvert_{V' \times V'}\rVert^2_2$$
where $\lVert S\rvert_{V' \times V'} \rVert_2$ is the $l^2$ norm as a matrix $A: V' \rightarrow V'$, $\lVert A\rVert_2^2 = \operatorname{Tr}(AA^T)$.

$\DeclareMathOperator\Span{Span}$If $v_1,\dotsc,v_n$ and $\lambda_1, \dotsc, \lambda_n$ are the (ordered) eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $S$ with $\lambda_1 > \lambda_2 > \dotsb > \lambda_n$ then I suspect that $$V = \Span({v_1,\dotsc,v_j}) + W$$
where $j$ is the minimal index such that $\dim(\Span(v_1,\dotsc,v_j) + W) = k$.

I've tried a few things such as replacing $S\rvert_{V' \times V'} = U^TSU$ where $U$ is a $k$-frame ($n \times k$ matrix with orthonormal columns) and then trying to use Lagrange multipliers but it hasn't worked out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not the right site for this type of question. Please try https://math.stackexchange.com/ instead. As for the question itself, there is no unique $V$, you can take anything that contains the eigenvector with the largest eigenvalue.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Can you elaborate? If W = 0 and $S$ has distinct non-zero eigenvalues then $V = \{v_1, v_3,...,v_{k+1}\}$ does not work.

Comment: I assume that by the norm you mean $\|S_V\|^2=\max_{v\in V, \|v\|=1} |\langle v, S v\rangle |$, which equals $\lambda_1$ for your $V$, so this works.

Comment: No, as stated the norm is l^2. I added a subscript to the formula clarity.

Comment: It's still not clear to me how you define $\|S_V\|$; maybe you can state it explicitly.

Comment: @ChristianRemling Please let me know if it is clear now.

Comment: It's clear now, thank you for the clarification. So you are considering the Hilbert-Schmidt norm of $PAP$, with $A$ corresponding to the original form and $P$ being the projection onto $V$.

Comment: What is the bigger research problem you are considering?